# How to get AmmId of a pair of tokens with Raydium pool

Tags: web3.js, serum, dex, swap

I'm trying to make a swap transaction between USDC and another token.
The instruction take the AmmId as a parameter.
How can I get that value if I only have the addresses of the tokens?